# Problem with keyboard on Del xps 12 9q33

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard, dell

I recently purchased a used Dell XPS 12 9q33. This is a Dell 2-in-1 laptop from about 2013. I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 dual booting with Windows 10 on this machine. Everything works great and Ubuntu 20.04 runs much faster than does Windows 10 except that there is an annoyance with the keyboard.If I type a word where there are two identical letters one after the other, such as 'too' then the second letter will not appear, e.g. I get 'to' unless I slow down my typing and make a small pause before repeating the letter. (If you look at my message you will so that I had to handle this issue quite a bit while creating this note!!) Any advice on how to correct this issue? Its specifically a Linux problem as the keyboard works fine under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

weird - the answer is to delete the .config/dconf/user file in my home directory. See about 3/4 down on the following web page.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-mint-84/keyboard-repeat-problem-on-dell-xps-12-running-mint-linux-17-2-a-4175559054/